# Is it possible to retrieve the submitted form info from HTTP packet using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a form using `method="post"`.
When it's submitted, the data in the form will be posted via HTTP packet - so they won't make the URL bar look messy.
The problem is I don't know how to retrieve the data using simple javascript running at client side.

Or alternatively, is it possible to recover the URL address bar after the user clicks submit? (As the URL would look like: `form.html?area1=x&area2=y&...` which makes the address bar full of characters. What I hope is to make it look identical to what it was before the user submits the form.)

Comment: *so they won't make the URL bar look messy.* - Let's be real, this is not a "good reason" to do a POST. Please, learn what POST/GET actually means and is good for; it's not a beauty contest.

Comment: I understand there are many issues around the difference between POST & GET like safety/security. However what I'm working on is a simple survey page and what I what to do is simply get some of the values without let all info submitted appear in the address bar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do that in client-side JavaScript; that's what a server is for. If you only need to pass variables between the same application, consider using URLs that differ in hash only to enable links; then, you don't even have to change pages, and you can keep the same data.

Answer (score 0):

What are you running on the client side?  Unless you're running node.js or something similar, javascript is client-side only.

Also, POST and GET have different meanings, it's not just about "how good it looks".

You might find [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) interesting in that matter.

Comment: I don't know what [this article](http://example.com) has to do with it. What's found there? How is it relevant? Why does anyone care?

Comment: It explains what different HTTP verbs are for, and why POST isn't just about making the URL look pretty.  The actual answer to the question is in the first paragraph, the rest is an additional comment that I thought was worth mentioning.